# SharePoint groups threshold

Tags: 2010, groups, threshold

I'm working on a solution where the system will create numerous groups based on different values in different custom lists. There's a good chance more than 3000 groups will be created.

What is the threshold for Groups in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SP2010 the supported limit for number of SPGroups per site collection is 10,000. This does not mean that you cannot create more than that.But if you do create all operations in the groups like add,delete user to group will be slower.

See this [Software Boundaries and limits for SP2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#SiteCollection)